# Should a new freelance photographer visit businesses without appointments

Tags: working-from-home

I've started work as freelance photographer since 6 months. I've been doing photography since 2 years but just recently after gaining much knowledge I prepared a good portfolio for architecture/interior, product, fashion photography.

I've been sending e-mails to clients with my portfolio attached. However the chances are that 1 out 10 actually reply. That's the scenario around here. E-mails aren't always the way to go.

Most of the clients I will visit are architecture firms. I'm targeting the small to medium sized firms to gain confidence in my work and set a base.

So I listed down the clients whom I would pitch my work to and I want to know if its okay to visit them to discuss about my service without taking an appointment?

What I think is -
If I have to wait for the decision maker for long period of time I'd obviously schedule an appointment for later. That way at least I have an appointment. Without visiting I wouldn't have the chance.

Please suggest

Comment: At one of my old jobs my desk was next to the front door and I was typically the one who had to greet unexpected guests. From my perspective, anyone that walked through that door trying to sell something was as bad as a telemarketer and I was openly hostile whenever I know my boss wouldn't mind. I'd recommend finding another way to pitch your business so you don't piss people off.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are trying to do some cold calling... How bout spending a bit more time in the office one day a week, and get ready for warm calling?

First, get a list of clients in your area you want to do work for. Make a contact card for each one, including their business name, address, phone number, email, hours, types of projects, managers, people with the buying decisions, etc. Keep these in a box on your desk or in your drawer.

Monday morning, get a small handful, and call each one. Ask to talk to someone responsible for  that would be able to give you a yes or no. Once you get that person (and write it down!), give a quick 5 second introduction, and see if they're even open to the idea of using a photographer for their projects. If not, you just saved gas money and time! You can still offer to be available if needed, and follow up a few months later.

On your contact card, write down any dates you promised to call people back, or visit them, and then transfer them to your calendar. Ensure you visit the people you promised you would, but don't feel bad about walking into some of their neighbouring offices and offer the same services (I mean to other companies around them). When you do visit a client, be very polite, and mention you were talking with  on the phone earlier, and wanted to give him more information. Offer your portfolio at this time, and get some face time with your potential clients.

As well, if you get a business card, that usually means they're quite busy, and don't want to tell you no to your face. Let them know you'll call back at a more convenient time, and keep their card. When you call back, do **NOT** apologize for disturbing them at work - they gave you their card so you can actually *call* them, so don't say sorry for bugging them.

Comment: Yes it was more like cold calling.
Firstly thanks for the input.

Let me try this method thoroughly for a week and work around it to make the sale every time. I believe the reason that I might have jumped to directly meeting people is because I used to e-mail only without making any direct calls to clients. 

I set myself a target to call atleast 5 clients a day to make it simpler for me to get used to this method. I still believe the best way to show someone what I'm capable of is by meeting them directly because in the end I'm selling myself. That's what separates me from the rest out there

Comment: *" in the end I'm selling myself. That's what separates me from the rest out there"* - That's what makes you like every other one out there. Always sell yourself

Answer (score 1):

Being the chief technology officer and web developer along with doing cad/cam design for multiple firms, and also working with very large companies such as Remington, Winchester, howa, savage, AR, Barrett and more I would suggest always making an appointment. I personally have always sort of resented when representatives showed up and wanted to leave a portfolio or take up some of my time without calling and scheduling an appointment first.

I run my business on the premise that I always want to look for new people with new ideas to keep my company with fresh & strong. Especially since  freelancers bring a lot of new ideas to the table and I'm always willing to schedule appointments and meet with people, so maybe the business that you're dealing with and the managers that were supposed to get back to you to make the appointments just aren't very good at doing their job in my opinion.

PS- I use LinkedIn to network and find my freelance workers.

Comment: Hi Kory, welcome to Freelancing.SE! I edited out your personal information, as we don't like signature-style parts to an answer.